# Vmware Combine Virtual Disks

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmware-player

It looks like when I set-up Vmware I chose the split the Virtual Disk option.  Well now I have over 30GB of vmdk files.  I do not want to loose my data that I have in the VM, so I do not want to re-install.

Is there a way of combining all the vmdk files into one, and set the VM to moving forward only use one vmdk file?

Comment: https://vmexpo.wordpress.com/2014/04/15/how-to-merge-multiple-vmdks-into-single-vmdk/comment-page-1/

Comment: Note that even if you merge all of your .vmdk files into a single one, that single .vmdk file will still take up over 30 GB.  Additionally, merging them all into a single file will make it [harder to shrink the .vmdk files later](http://superuser.com/a/977430/210417).

Comment: @jamesdlin - do I have an option then to reduce the amount of disk space that the VM is taking up?

Comment: Yes, it's calling shrinking.  Go to VM > Settings > Hardware > Hard Disk > Compact.  For a Windows guest, there's also VM > Manage > Clean up Disks which is more efficient (but which is specific to NTFS guest file systems).